# How to write column names with whitespace in diesel model.rs?

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I am trying to use `Diesel` to manage my database to use with `Rocket` and i got stuck at writing the models.rs for my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `problemSet` (
  `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `contestId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `difficulty` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `binary search` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `chinese remainder theorem` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `constructive algorithms` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `data structures` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `dfs and similar` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `divide and conquer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
  );
```

Here, I am confused for how to write the identifiers in struct of models.rs for column_names with whitespaces.

I was referring to official guide of Diesel and RUST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining the schema, you can use the `sql_name` attribute to specify a name for a column that is different to the name as it will appear in rust code:

```
diesel::table! {
    problemSet {
        ...
        #[sql_name = "divide and conquer"]
        divide_and_conquer -> Text,
        ...
    }
}
```

See: [documentation for the table! macro](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/macro.table.html)

Having said that, my preference would be to keep away from spaces in column names.

Comment: Thanks @harmic , this worked but i think your suggestion of not having spaces is much better ,therefore i am working on that. :)